# How to add a collapsable ag-Grig row without the use of ag-Grid Enterprise

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, rows, ag-grid

I am in need of adding a collaspable row to ag-Grid to each row of data. Each row of data has further data regarding it but I don't have the possibility to use enterprise and so no Master/detail functionality.

I have seen the use of full width rows, but I need to be able to show/hide them at a click of a button on the row.

Any help would be great!! Thanks

Comment: Hi Jason, your question is a few days old now. It will certainly help a lot if you can edit your post and add any code that you're currently trying. Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.